# How to get IndexReader from custom request handler?

Tags: solr, requesthandler

This is extension of my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393908/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-implement-terms-association-mining-in-solr).

I'm going to create **custom request handler** to provide terms association mining over existing index. In order to do this I need access to Solr's `IndexReader` opened on *default* index directory.

The only way to do this I can think of is to get [`IndexReaderFactory`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/core/IndexReaderFactory.html) by invoking [`SolrQueryRequest`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/request/SolrQueryRequest.html).[`getCore()`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/request/SolrQueryRequest.html#getCore()).[`getIndexReaderFactory()`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/core/SolrCore.html#getIndexReaderFactory()). This factory has method `newReader()` which seems to be what I need. But this method requires index directory as its first argument.

Here's my question: **is it correct way** to get IndexReader? If so, how can I **get Solr's index directory**? Can I access Solr configuration to find it from my code or should I go with something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer myself while reading `LukeRequestHandler` source:

```
SolrIndexSearcher searcher = req.getSearcher();
IndexReader reader = searcher.getReader();
```

So they first get searcher, and only then reader.